# How to compare fields inside an embedded array with the field at root level?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I Have a MongoDB with 2 collections, and I'm struggling with how to do a complex query involving those 2 collections.

My environment is nodejs with mongoose.

I saw that maybe *aggregate* would be the thing to use but I'm not sure.

My Collections :

1)  User collection

```
{
    "_id":{"$oid":"xxxxxxx"},
    …
}
```

2)  Chat collection

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "aaaaaaa"
    },
    "participants": [
        {
            "user": {
                "$oid": "xxxxxxxxx"
            },
            "lastRead": {
                "$date": {
                    "$numberLong": "1562673141916"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "user": {
                "$oid": "zzzzzzzzz"
            },
            "lastRead": {
                "$date": {
                    "$numberLong": "1562683663751"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "lastMessageAt": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1562673141867"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I query the chat collection to retrieve, not the chats, but the users (unique if possible) that have unread messages (participant.lastRead < lastMessageAt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.chat.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind:"$participants"
    },
    {
        $match:{
            $expr:{
                $lt:["$participants.lastRead","$lastMessageAt"]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":null,
            "users":{
                $addToSet:"$participants.user"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Comment: Thank you very much its working nicely!
I have a last question: 
my chat model does not embed the user, I use population when needed. 
How can I add population with this query here, I need to retrieve full users.

Comment: @PhoenK You can directly `$lookup` the `users` array into the ```User``` collection. Please check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/. Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Thanks, was trying that yesterday and figured it out with your confirmation !